# asp.net mvc2 actionlink with parameters similar to getelementbyid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, actionlink

My Action link is as follows:
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("linktext", "actionName", "controllerName", new {area="areaName",**id = "abcd"**, productURLName = "choc"}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "SFS", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { style = "color:#00FF00" })%>

I need to get the value of a control in runtime and pass it as parameter in place of "abcd".

In javascript I can do getelementbyId. Is there anything I can do in this case.

To get similar functionality I have also tried jquery ajax, but in that case the controller action is not even getting called, at least the action link works::

function SendInvite() {

```
              var url = "areaName/controllerName/actionName/" + document.getElementById("BasicUserInfo").value + "?productURLName=choc";
              $.post(url, function (data) {
                                        if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {
                                            $("#result").append("Invite Sent");
                                        } else {
                  $("#result").append("Error, Please try later");
                                        }
              });
          }
```

Thanks
Arnab

Comment: I found the 2 following links which suggest I can't use ajax.actionlink, so the only option seems to be jquery, but even that's not working:(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030124/mvc2-how-can-i-read-control-values-for-an-action-link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856518/passing-textbox-value-using-html-actionlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your jQuery code at click event of the link. For example this is your link:

```
<%:Html.ActionLink("linkText", "actionName", "controllerName", new {area="areaName",id = "abcd", productURLName = "choc"},  new {@class="myclass", style = "color:#00FF00" })%>
```

Then you have to write jQuery function that hooks the click event of this link. Here I'm using class selector:

```
 $(".myclass").live('click', function(){
                  var url = "areaName/controllerName/actionName/" + document.getElementById("BasicUserInfo").value + "?productURLName=choc";
                  $.post(url, function (data) {
                                            if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {
                                                $("#result").append("Invite Sent");
                                            } else {
                      $("#result").append("Error, Please try later");
                                            }
                  });
return false;


    });
```

You can also get URL in event handler using:

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: Thanks but creating the entire link like this won't help, the value of id will come from javascript "document.getElementById("BasicUserInfo").value" but the value of productURL comes from .net aspx code.
So I need to pass the productURL code to the javascript which will get the id value and create a link and then ajax call..

Comment: You can keep asp.net things in Html.ActionLink and move other things to jquery

Comment: got it, added the first parameter in asp.net, sent the url to js and there added the second param.
Tx

Comment: problem, it is going to the controller but not coming back to the page   but going to the link created using html.actionlink ( b4 concatenating using js).
My controller code returns just True or False

Comment: @Arnab sorry, just forgot that u need to return false at the end of click method so it does not perform the default operation that is of course going to that particular url

Answer (score 1):

You may get rid of MicrosoftAjax and try like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "linktext", 
    "actionName", 
    "controllerName", 
    new { area = "areaName", productURLName = "choc" }, 
    new { style = "color:#00FF00", id = "myLink" }
) %>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function() {
        var id = $('#BasicUserInfo').val();
        $.post(this.href, { id: id, productURLName: 'choc' }, function(result) {
            $('#SFS').html(result);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: In my case, I can get the productURLName only in asp.net and not js.