# How to pass Kendo drop-down list selected value from Html.RenderAction to action method in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need to pass the value of a Kendo drop-down list to the action method within a controller from a Html.RenderAction helper.  I can't for the life of me recall how to do this. How do I pass the selected value to the controller?  This would be the same method you would use for a normal drop-down list.

```
// Drop-down list
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
  .Name("dropDownList")
  .DataTextField("Text")
  .DataValueField("Value")
  .OptionLabel("Please select")   
  .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>
  {
      new SelectListItem
      {
          Text = "Test 1",
          Value = "1"
      },
      new SelectListItem
      {
          Text = "Test 2",
          Value = "2"
      },
      new SelectListItem
      {
          Text = "Test 3",
          Value = "3"
      }
  }))

// RenderAction
@{Html.RenderAction("DoSomething", new { value = %dropDownListSelectedValue% }); }

// Controller
public ActionResult DoSomething(string value)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I would think about using an Ajax request on change of the DDL

Comment: Yeah, I could do.  But I can't seem to find a definitive answer on how to pass a value from a control (e.g. textbox, dropdown-list) from a Html.Action or Html.RenderAction to the controller.

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856518/passing-textbox-value-using-html-actionlink